# Convex Functions: Proofs

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f$ be a monotone nondecreasing function of a single variable which is also convex.  Let $g$ be a convex function defined on a convex set $G$.  Is it true that the composition of these functions $f \circ g$ is strictly convex if and only if $f$ is monotone increasing?  Are there other requirements?

Further,

Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable on a region $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I am to show that a sufficient condition for a point $x^*$ in the interior of $A$ to be a relative minimum point of $f$ is that $f(x^*) = 0$ and that $f$ be locally convex at $x^*$. I am not sure how to go about showing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for the first question, just take the 2nd derivative of the composition $f \circ g$

Comment: @neticin What if it's not twice differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question per question, please.

1. Yes, because for $0\le \lambda\le 1$ and for every $a,b$
   $$f(g((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b))\le f((1-\lambda)g(a)+\lambda g(b))\le (1-\lambda)f(g(a))+\lambda f(g(b))) $$
2. Suppose $x^*$ is not a point of relative minimum. There there is a nearby point $x^{**}$ with $f(x^{**})<f(x^*)$. Consider the function $g(t)=f((1-t)x^*+tx^{**})$ for $0\le t\le 1$. This function  is convex (why?). Since $g(t)\le (1-t)f(x^*)+tf(x^{**})$, it follows that 
   $$
   \frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t} \le f(x^{**}) - f(x^*) <0
   \tag{1}$$
   On the other hand, $g'(0)=0$ by the chain rule. This contradicts (1).

Comment: @Stopwatch $g$ is convex because $f$ is, no other reason needed.